# Ubuntu 19.10 login screen rectangles instead of letters

Tags: login, screen

[image]

i have a problem visible in the picture. When I turn on the laptop login screen is ok, the problem occurs when I log out or when I go to change the user. then I have a screen like this. Please help, thank you

Comment: You've changed the theme or icon pack, or edited a .css file. Put the original back.

Comment: Thanks i instaled font and now its ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

User had installed a theme/icon pack that caused the problem. Removed it and it's OK again.